# Compute the moment of inertia about the z-axis

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, multiple-integral

> Compute the moment of inertia about the z-axis of the following objects with density, delta.
>
> (a). The sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2\le a^2$
>
> (b). The cylinder $x^2+y^2\le a^2$, $0\le z\le h$.

My attempt:

(a). Mass= $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$($\delta$)

radius of disk: $y=(a^2-x^2)^\frac{1}{2}$

volume of disk: $\pi(a^2-x^2)dx$

mass=(Density)(volume)=$(\delta)\pi(a^2-x^2)dx$
moment of inertia=[(mass of disk)(radius)^2]/2

[integral]: $[-a,a]$  $I=[\dfrac{(\pi)(\delta)}{2}][(a^2-x^2)^2dx]$

(kinda stuck here... not sure if this is right or in the right direction)

TEXTBOOK ANSWER: $\dfrac{2}{5}a^2(\delta\dfrac{4}{3}(\pi)a^3)=(\dfrac{2}{5}a^2)$(*mass of sphere*)

(b). radius=$a$

height=$h$,  $0\le z\le h$
[integral]: $[0,M]$ I=[(dM)(a^2)/2]
                        =[(a^2/2)(M)]
                        =((a^2)/2)((pi)(a^2)(h)(delta))

\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
I&=[(dM)(a^2)]/2 \\
&= \dfrac{a^2}{2}M \\
&= (\dfrac{a^2}{2})(\pi a^2h)(\delta)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
(again... I'm not confident that this is correct)

TEXTBOOK ANSWER: $\dfrac{a^2}{2}((\delta)(\pi)(a^2)(h))=(1/2)(a^2)$(*mass of cylinder*)

Comment: It's generally expected that you will format your maths with MathJax.  it takes a little time to learn but is really useful once you get the hang of it: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference (and it makes life a lot easier for any users wanting to help you, too).

Comment: okay, thank you!